# Any SAP (structural analysis program) software in linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, free-software

I'm looking for any software like ETABS, SAP2000, Autodesk RSA (ROBOT), Graitec Advance Design, SCIA, STRAP, STAAD. I don't need simple 2D frame solver. I'm looking for fully fledged 3D, nonlinear, dynamic and seismic analysis capable software. Structural codes dimensioning and yield strength checkings would be really sweet. It doesn't matter if it's free or commercial.
Code-Aster and Salome are too 'academic' and hard to manipulate. They don't provide any structural codes support. They look more like Ansys (physics software, not structural specific).

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point would be like these ones: bars3d (sourceforge.net/projects/bars3d), Estru3D (sourceforge.net/projects/estru3d) and Frame3DD (frame3dd.sourceforge.net). Sadly, i couldn't make any of those work on my Xubuntu 16. Estru3D installs fine, but it won't start at all. Anyway, these 3 are very crude projects, i'm looking for something more advanced.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps some of these meets your expectations:

FreeCAD is a general purpose Open Source 3D CAD/MCAD/CAx/CAE/PLM modeler, 
aimed directly at mechanical engineering and product design but also fits 
in a wider range of uses around engineering, such as architecture or other 
engineering specialties.
[Site](http://www.freecadweb.org/)

SolveSpace is an Open Source 2D and 3D CAD program. 
It is a constraint-based parametric modeler with simple mechanical 
simulation capabilities.
[Site](http://solvespace.com/index.pl)

VARKON is a free CAD system and high level development tool for Engineering,
Computer Aided Design and Product Modeling applications.
[Site](http://varkon.sourceforge.net/)

gCAD3D is a 3D CAD CAM application that features an integrated 3D OpenGL viewer,a program interpreter for geometry and NC-commands in 3D, an integrated NC-processor, and a programming interface for user programs.
[Site](http://www.gcad3d.org/)

OpenSCAD is a software for creating solid 3D CAD objects. 
Unlike most free software for creating 3D models (such as the famous application Blender) it does not focus on the artistic aspects of 3D modelling but instead on the CAD aspects. 
[Site](http://www.openscad.org/)

Comment: I found this commercial solution: TNO DIANA (http://tnodiana.com/SolutionsEarthquake). No publicity intended. But i can't find any anybody using this software. Any comments are welcomed.

Comment: None of the listed softwares answer the question, the question is about a structural analysis software to calculate beam , pole ,slab ,etc ... to clarify using the available windows softwares :an alternative to  Autodesk Robot , Graitec Advance ...But Not the Autodesk Autocad